# Eloquent methods lumen

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have belongsToMany relationship between items and vehicle.

items can be assigned to multiple vehicles. same vehicle can b assigned to multiple items. so my pivot table item_vehicle have extra column date which will show that when vehicle is assigned to item.

here is my query.

```
select `items`.`id`, `items`.`name`, `items`.`area` as `total_area`,
`item_vehicle`.`date`, `vehicles`.`name` as `vehicle_name`,
SUM(parcel_vehicle.area) as processed_area
from `parcels`
inner join `item_vehicle` on `item_vehicle`.`p_id` = `items`.`id`
inner join `vehicles` on `item_vehicle`.`t_id` = `vehicles`.`id` 
where `item_vehicle`.`date` < '?' and `items`.`processed` = ? and `vehicles`.`name`=?
```

group by `items`.`id`
what will be the eloquent way of doing this

```
Item::with(['vehicle'=>function($q){$q->wherePivot('date','<','2019/2/12');}])->whereHas('vehicle',function($q){$q->where('vehicles.id','2');})->where('processed',1)->where('id',4)
->get();
```

my concerns is it should run only one query

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes will share that. and dont know much about how it works. my concern is run all this conditions in one go

Answer (score 1):

```
$parcels = Parcel::join('item_vehicle', 'item_vehicle.pid', '=' ,'items.id')
->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=' ,'item_vehicle.t_id')
->where('item_vehicle.date', '<', $date)
->where('items.processed', $processed)
->where('vehicles.name', $vehicleName)
->select(
    'items.id',
    'items.name',
    \DB::raw('items.area as total_area'),
    'item_vehicle.date',
    \DB::raw('vehicles.name as vehicle_name'),
    \DB::raw('SUM(parcel_vehicle.area) as processed_area')
)
->groupBy('items.id')
->get();
```

However, you have non-aggregated columns in select and you are doing group by. To make  this work you might need to disable mysql's `only_full_group_by` mode

Comment: so only way is query builder

Comment: You can use model relationships which will eager load but if want to join as per your raw query, my best bet it using what I have mentioned above.